# Add element to next unused index - C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm sure others have already asked this, but is it possible to insert an element into the next available index of an array without using a for-loop to find that index first? Almost like a list.add() function but for arrays in C.

Comment: If you do the bookkeeping yourself, it is.

Comment: If it's really list functionality you want you could implement a simple linked list instead of using arrays, for example like this: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson15.html

Comment: Now that you mention it, I don't know why I'm not using a list. I'll do that. Thanks.

Comment: Great, I'll add it as an answer then.

Comment: How can you tell which element in the array is the first one not in use?  Couldn't you keep a record of that index number, and then assign the new value to the available position, and then increment the index number for the next available element -- making sure you don't overflow the size of the array.  Note that a full-blown list implies dynamic memory allocation, which has consequences for cleanup that arrays (that are not dynamically allocated) do not have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, you will have to loop through the array.

Answer (score 1):

If it's really list functionality you want you could implement a simple linked list instead of using arrays, for example like this: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson15.html